# Sufficient criteria for uniform convergence of a series of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'm currently studying sequences and series of functions, and I've begun doing exercises. I've soon found that, while using the definition of uniform convergence is viable for sequences of functions, it is not so much for series of functions. My question is: are there known sufficient conditions for uniform convergence of such series? (If so, I'd be grateful if you could point me to a proof of the tests).

Thank you in advance.

E.G.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^n}{n!x^n},x\in \mathbb{R^+}$$
I have found that the series converges point-wise for $x>e$ and diverges for $0<x\leq e$. The convergence is obviously absolute but not total, since $\sup_{x\in]e,+\infty[}f_n(x)=\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ which diverges using Stirling's formula. I don't know how to proceed with uniform convergence though.

Comment: A series is a sequence; namely the sequence of its partial sums.

Comment: Well yeah, but if for sequences the function to which the sequence converges pointwise is easily established and so finding the sup for every term is in many cases not very hard, for series you don't immediately have the function to which the series converges and so applying the definition is in many cases harder. Am I missing something?

Comment: No. That's a good point. In many cases, you can show a series is uniformly Cauchy to establish uniform convergence (this is what the [Weierstrass $M$-test](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWeierstrass_M-test&ei=BWBuU6yHDoWqyASZk4KoCQ&usg=AFQjCNFLwaYvG0mlE_2hjMvjk6nKYwZQWg&bvm=bv.66330100,d.aWw) does).

Comment: Oh! I'd never heard of the M-test. Thank you. Do you know of any others?

Comment: [This paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fohkawa.cc.it-hiroshima.ac.jp%2FAoPS.pdf%2FMathStudio%2FUniform%2520Convergence-chapter4.pdf&ei=iGBuU_yGK8akyAT7yoGYDQ&usg=AFQjCNFxhEE0BpYWmhk3gzU4amG_-qcVtw&bvm=bv.66330100,d.aWw&cad=rja) seems to contain the standard theorems. See in particular Dirichlet's test on page 34.

Comment: I was wondering, aren't the hypothesis in the Weierstrass M-test basically those of total convergence?

Comment: What do you mean by "total convergence"? (The $M$-test's result gives absolute and uniform convergence.)

Comment: Basically that the numerical series of the supremums of the functions $f_n(x)$ converges. Might be only a local denomination though. It basically IS the Weierstrass test.